# fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, git-clone

soy nuevo con git.
Hice un git clone de un repositorio de github, y luego de hacer un pequeño cambio, hice un git status para ver el estado del mismo, y me sale el siguiente mensaje:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

¿Qué es lo que debo hacer?

Gracias,

Comment: Perdón, ya lo resolví. No estaba dentro del directorio correcto. Una vez que hice git clone, debía ingresar al repositorio local con "cd" nombre-del-repositorio-local. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Escribe

```
git remote -v
```

Si no te da la lista de repositorios utilizados es que por alguna razon no lo creo correctamente. Debes reinicializarlo

```
git init
```

Luego anadir el repositorio remoto que le tengas.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```